# How to apply rolling function to find the number of previous true boolean values using R

Tags: r, dplyr, zoo

Is it possible to create a column which is the rolling count of the number of boolean true values from the previous 4 rows, also partitioned by another column?

The example below shows the desired result, where the output column is the count of the number of true values for the previous 4 rows - this is also partitioned by the first column. Is there a way of doing this with dplyr?

Example data:

```
a   2016-01-01  TRUE
a   2016-01-02  TRUE
a   2016-01-03  FALSE
a   2016-01-04  FALSE
a   2016-01-05  FALSE
a   2016-01-06  FALSE
a   2016-01-07  FALSE
a   2016-01-08  TRUE
a   2016-01-09  TRUE
a   2016-01-10  TRUE
a   2016-01-11  TRUE
b   2016-01-01  TRUE
b   2016-01-02  TRUE
b   2016-01-03  FALSE
b   2016-01-04  TRUE
b   2016-01-05  FALSE
b   2016-01-06  TRUE
b   2016-01-07  TRUE
b   2016-01-08  FALSE
b   2016-01-09  FALSE
b   2016-01-10  FALSE
b   2016-01-11  FALSE
```

Desired outcome:

```
a   2016-01-01  TRUE   0
a   2016-01-02  TRUE   1
a   2016-01-03  FALSE  2
a   2016-01-04  FALSE  2
a   2016-01-05  FALSE  2
a   2016-01-06  FALSE  1
a   2016-01-07  FALSE  0
a   2016-01-08  TRUE   0
a   2016-01-09  TRUE   1
a   2016-01-10  TRUE   2
a   2016-01-11  TRUE   3
b   2016-01-01  TRUE   0
b   2016-01-02  TRUE   1
b   2016-01-03  FALSE  2
b   2016-01-04  TRUE   2
b   2016-01-05  FALSE  3
b   2016-01-06  TRUE   2
b   2016-01-07  TRUE   2
b   2016-01-08  FALSE  3
b   2016-01-09  FALSE  2
b   2016-01-10  FALSE  2
b   2016-01-11  FALSE  1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group_by()` and take advantage of the fact that boolean also have numeric representations.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df %>%
  group_by(col1, col2) %>%
  mutate(col4 = rollsum(col3, k = 4) - col3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Boolean values count as 1 for T and 0 for F, so you can leverage that to use cumsum.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(total = cumsum(col2)-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R answer:

```
df$col4<- cumsum(lag(df$col2, 4, default = 0))
```